# Configure different timeouts in gunicorn for different endpoints?

Tags: python, rest, gunicorn, session-timeout

Gunicorn allows configuring a timeout for requests, as demonstrated in their documentation below. This seems to be a global configuration for the entire application.

Is it possible to configure different timeouts for different endpoints? Perhaps overriding the default timeout on url endpoints that are known to take a long time?

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#timeout

> timeout
>
> -t INT, --timeout INT
>
> 30
>
> Workers silent for more than this many seconds are killed and restarted.
>
> Generally set to thirty seconds. Only set this noticeably higher if
>   you’re sure of the repercussions for sync workers. For the non sync
>   workers it just means that the worker process is still communicating
>   and is not tied to the length of time required to handle a single
>   request.

Comment: This issue is quite old and I don't know if things has changed from then but anyway this is the closest thing I could find: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/724

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy way to do what you want to do. Probably the best option is to package each endpoint into a separate application, and then launch them with their own separate gunicorn processes / workers with the appropriate timeouts. Then put something like nginx to proxy the endpoints to different gunicorn processes.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know this is a good solution or not. But I did something like this:

1. install [gevent](https://www.gevent.org/) :

```
pip install gevent
```

2. create a [custom worker](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-class) for gunicorn:

```
# gunicorn_config.py

import gevent
from gunicorn.workers.ggevent import GeventWorker

ADMIN_TIMEOUT = 30  # second
API_TIMEOUT = 5


class CustomWorker(GeventWorker):
    def handle_request(self, listener_name, req, sock, addr):
        try:
            if req.path.startswith('/admin'):
                timeout = ADMIN_TIMEOUT
            else:
                timeout = API_TIMEOUT
           
            with gevent.Timeout(timeout):
                super().handle_request(listener_name, req, sock, addr)
        except gevent.GreenletExit:
            pass
        except SystemExit:
            pass
        except gevent.timeout.Timeout:
            print(f'timeout for {req.path}')
            raise StopIteration()
```

3. run gunicorn:

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 MyProject.wsgi -k 'gunicorn_config.CustomWorker'
```